# Passing partially populated Model to Create page without initializing other properties to default

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET MVC 5

I have a strongly typed create page.

My model is like this,

```
public class DemoViewModel
{
    public int PackageId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

my view is like this,

```
@model DemoViewModel

<div >
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PackageId)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PackageId)
</div>
<div >
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
</div>
```

When the page is called, the PackageId is selected. So in my control I call the view like this,

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new DemoViewModel() { 
        PackageId = 1
    });
}
```

**The problem is that when I call like above the Date field get initialized to default and it shows "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" in the textbox**. It is ok (that means empty when load) if I call the view without an model instance. But I need to pass some initial Model data to the view.

How can I pass an partially populated instance of mode without showing default values in other fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your properties to be set to default value, you have to make them nullable by adding `?`

So, in your case Date would be:

```
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper method which takes as a parameter your model, binds it to the view, but excludes the `Date` property while binding, and then returns that view.

```
private GetCreateViewExcludingDate([Bind(Exclude="Date")]DemoViewModel demoVM)
{
    return View("Create",demoVM);
}
```

And in your `Create` action method,

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return GetCreateViewExcludingDate(new DemoViewModel() { 
        PackageId = 1
    });
}
```

Of course, the other alternative is what @Mark said. Make your `Date` property nullable. But then you will have to check for null values in your controller whenever you use it.

**EDIT:**

As @sajith mentions in the comments, this solution **DOES NOT WORK**.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is an alternate solution. The textbox can be cleared on the client side using JavaScript/jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("input#Date").val("");
});
```

I tried this and it works fine.

Comment: Bind attribute provide details about how model binding should occur. Calling another action will not invoke model binding. Usually it invokes with a Http Request.

Comment: @sajith You are right. Very silly overlook on my part. So why not just pass the `DemoViewModel` as a paramter to the `Create` method and exclude the property there? This will cause ambiguity between the `GET` and `POST` `Create` methods, which you can resolve by adding a dummy parameter (`routeValues` or something) to the `POST` `Create` method.

Kludgy solution, but will work.

Comment: Passing the DemoViewModel as a parameter will not work. When get called, Instance of DemoViewModel is passed. So all the properties ware set to default.

Comment: @sajith Oh, I see the problem. An instance of `DemoViewModel` will always be bound to the view, and the `Date` property will always have some value, since it is not nullable. But now that I think about it, this is an issue of how you will display the value on client side. If the value is the default value of `DateTime`, you wish to show an empty textbox. I think this should be handled on the client side using JavaScript. Thoughts?

Comment: No I don't think so. In MVC strongly types Create page, In GET request, an instant of object is not passed (render only an empty form). Where MVC framework use the object type's metadata to populate the view when render and all the fields (textboxes) are empty. So we don't need to empty explicitly in client side. Problem here is that I want to pass some initial data to the view. So object instance is passed to view.

Comment: @sajith I didn't get your point. I was able to clear the textbox using a simple JavaScript script.

Comment: You are correct, yes you can clear the textbox but the problem is that you need to do that in initial load only. Say, you fill the form and submit and there are validation fail in server side. when the form is reloaded, the values entered by user will get cleared.

Comment: @sajith I can think of another kludgy solution to subvert this problem. Set a flag indicating `GET` or `POST` in the `ViewBag` in the controller action methods, and then in the script, read this value, and clear the textbox if `GET`. Too much kludge?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52291/discussion-between-sajith-and-amateurprogrammer)